# php regex for detecting and replacing text links with anchor tags

Tags: php, regex, for-loop, hyperlink

I got this regex off of a site forum to look for links in text and replace them with html links so that they are clickable.

the problem came when someone input one of those new youtube links that look like this:

http://youtu.be/djKd189-ag2

What happens is the link is made up to the dash and then -ag2 is left on it's own.

I don't know enough about php regex to even dare alter this to add parsing the dash so I was hoping I could get some help:

```
$newText = preg_replace('@((http|https)://([\w-.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', 
             '<a href="$1" class="link1" target="_blank">$1</a>',$text);
```

I am guessing it's somewhere around the \S+ part

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert plain text URLs into HTML hyperlinks in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php) is the source of your butchered regex, works, and only took one search to find(!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newText = preg_replace('@((http|https)://([\w-.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_-.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', 
             '<a href="$1" class="link1" target="_blank">$1</a>',$text);
```

You need just a '-' where it's written '[\w/_.]'

Comment: I tried to use that but I am getting an error from php : PHP Warning &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;preg_replace(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 42&#039;