# how to replace URL with same hyperlink in html

Tags: html, tags

I am trying to add link of same hyperlink of same link in html but it not linking

in html
simple add a link `http://www.test.com/test`

but link is not generating

I want to change automatically result as `<a href="http://www.test.com/test">http://www.test.com/test</a>`
for example  http://www.test.com/test

Comment: would the link be a user input, so behaving similar to StackOverflow transforming URL's into linked URL's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: yes the link is input by user with text like StackOverflow comment

Comment: have a look at the duplicate i suggested...

Comment: thanks @webeno my question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php

Comment: well, go ahead and use that solution then and delete this question... no need to have 2 about the same... ;)

Comment: but question is not deleted, error massage comes (Sorry, this question has answers...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple script.

Step 1: Add hyperlink with id

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link Comes Here</a>
```

Step 2: On dom ready get page url and update the href value with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var url = window.location.href; 
     // if you have static url you can hard code like
     // var url = "http://www.url.com"; 
     $("#link").attr("href", url)
});
```

Comment: make sure you provide information on jQuery; it might be self-explanatory to you, but the OP hasn't even mentioned javascript at all, so you cannot be sure they know what jQuery is...

Answer (score 0):

try this in you HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/test"><span>http://www.test.com/test</span></a>
```

else try to use jquery like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/test" id="myLink"></a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myLink").text("http://www.test.com/test");
});
```