# How to make link in magento frontend

Tags: magento

I want to make link in magento frontend in my module there is comment box so i want if any customer or guest use any url in comment that time it will be displayed as link so how to make it please give me example how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$string = 'I have some texts here and also links such as http://www.youtube.com  http://www.haha.com and lol@example.com. They are ready to be replaced.';

function makeClickableLinks($s) {
    return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
}

echo makeClickableLinks($string);
?>
```

this answer refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/3525863/2522817