# Change links in text to links without changing html tags

Tags: php, regex

I have written some code that change text links to links but it also changes the `src` attribute of my `img` tags to link like

```
<img src="some url"/><br>
http://google.com<br>
http://beezfeed.cu.ma<br>
```

Here my code change it to

```
<img src="<a href="some url">some url</a>"/><br>
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a><br>
<a href="http://beezfeed.cu.ma">http://beezfeed.cu.ma</a><br>
```

I want it to leave img tag and do that thing with only text. Here is my code

```
function make_links_clickable($text){
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#? &;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert plain text URLs into HTML hyperlinks in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) then strip html tags to avoid img tag

```
$str = '<img src="some url"/><br>
http://google.com<br>
http://beezfeed.cu.ma<br>';
$arr = explode('<br>', $str);
foreach($arr as $a){
    if(!empty($a)){
        $a = strip_tags($a);
        echo '<a href="'.$a.'">'.$a.'</a>';
    }
}
```