# Replace all URLs in text to clickable links in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I have a web application written with PHP. I wanted to find all URLs inside users comments and change them to clickable links. I searched many websites and pages and found the solution below (Unfortunately I did not find its reference link again):

```
<?php
function convert($input) {
   $pattern = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
   return $output = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="http$2://$4">$0</a>', $input);
}
?>
```

This code works perfectly thanks to its author. But I found out there is a bug in it that I could not solve.
If detected URL started with **s** letter (without https), the **href** value won't have that **s** character and **http** will change to **https**, whereas inner text is correct.

**Example:**
source.com >> `<a href="https://ource.com">source.com</a>`

Do you have any solution to solve this bug?

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/oZ1uG6/1

Comment: @splash58 did you checked your test result? It returned `<a href="http://s">source.com</a>`

Comment: Are u try it (http)?()?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn it is not working

Comment: @MohammadSaberi https://www.regex101.com/r/oZ1uG6/3

Comment: @splash58: result in my local <a href="http://s">source.com</a> xD

Comment: @FirstOne no it is the wrong result when input is source.com

Comment: @MohammadSaberi Take code from my answer

Comment: [Convert plain text URLs into HTML hyperlinks in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function convert($input) {
   $pattern = '@(http(s)?://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
   return $output = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="http$2://$3">$0</a>', $input);
}
```

**[demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/oZ1uG6/3)**

Comment: This works - better than others found via the googles. And I note that it also works with URIs that contain those pesky umlauts .

Huzzah !!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! What are the `@` symbols in the beginning and end of the pattern? Instead if `/REGEX_PATTERN/` slashes?

Comment: @MohammadAlBanna Yes, you can use some char as delimiter, not only slash - https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: I don't know why this answer was accepted, but this will also convert any word followed by a dot followed by something else into an anchor. For example: Vestibulum pretium nibh eu sollicitudin tincidunt.</p> this will convert " tincidunt" into an anchor

Comment: Not to mention that this answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 5):

```
function convert($input) {
   $pattern = '@(http(s)?://)?(([a-zA-Z0-9])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
   return $output = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="http$2://$3">$0</a>', $input);
}
```

This is an update of the @splash58 dude answer to handle the URL which starts with number instead of letter. Example is 11hub.net or 9gag.com

Thank you splash58 for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '@(http(s)?://)?(([a-zA-Z0-9])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.<]+[^\s<]*)+[^,.\s<])@';
```

This is an update of the @splash58 answer and @Gero Nikolov answer.
If the text ends with the < character, an error occurs.

Example:

```
<p>some text https://example.com</p>
```

Result:

```
<p>some text <a href="https://example.com</p>">https://example.com</p></a>
```

With the specified pattern, the result will be correct.