# Automatically make email link, url link in a static text

Tags: php, regex

I have a text from user input. In the text includes all kind emails and links start with "http/https/www".
For example: I have a text like below.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor email@foo.com sit amet https://foo.com/path?query=string 
Lorem ipsum foo.com www.foo.com Lorem ipsum dolor
```

Exected output would be.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="mailto:email@foo.com>email@foo.com</a> sit amet <a href="https://foo.com/path?query=string">https://foo.com/path?query=string</a>
Lorem ipsum <a href="foo.com">foo.com</a> <a href="www.foo.com">www.foo.com</a> Lorem ipsum dolor
```

Comment: It would be greate if I can use php to solve the problem, otherwise I'll use [this javascript library](https://alexcorvi.github.io/anchorme.js/) as a last resort

Comment: I've edited the solution :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert plain text URLs into HTML hyperlinks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please refer this [demo](https://eval.in/810544)

```
<?php
$linkArray = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet','email@gmail.com','google.com','https://www.google.com'];
foreach($linkArray as $link){
    if(preg_match('/((https:\/\/)?([A-z]+@)?([A-z]+)?\.([A-z]+)?)/',$link,$match)){
        if(preg_match('/(@)/',$link,$m)){
            echo '<a href="mailto:'.$match[1].'">'.$match[1].'</a><br>';    
        }else{
            echo '<a href="'.$match[1].'">'.$match[1].'</a><br>';
        }
    }else{
        echo $link.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering,
So I need to explode the text by space to get $linkArray, right?
`$linkArray = explode(' ', $text)`

Comment: No that won't work I guess, you can make array from `/n`. From where you are getting that string?

Comment: From where you are getting that string? << Users input.
So I want a function to work on all kind of strings that include any emails or any urls.

Comment: Then you can explode by newline, that would help you.