# Convert text with link into clickable - error

Tags: php

So based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I have the following code which almost works, with the exception that clean is returning an error

> syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER)

```
$url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i';
$clean = str_replace(['https://', 'http://', 'www.'], '', $0);
$html = '<a href="$0" target="_blank" title="$0">'.$clean.'</a>';
$questionLinks = preg_replace($url, $html, $question->question);
```

The problem is with the $0, how can I have a normal variable to work with?

Comment: and what's the content of `$0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: I'm not sure what is $0 apparently it returns the whole URL, but I can't find documentation. And sadly it's not a duplicate, I can't solve my question with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i';
preg_match($url, $question->question, $completeUrl);
$clean = preg_replace('~^www.~', '', $completeUrl[2]);
$http = strpos($question->question, 'http');
$html = ($http ? '<a href="$0" target="_blank" title="$0">'.$clean.'</a>' : '<a href="http://$0" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>');
$questionLinks = preg_replace($url, $html, $question->question);
```