# text to link, problem with link that has not https

Tags: php, regex

Users can add texts. This texts can have links.

I'd like do add click to it.

The problem is, some links works like:

http://www.example.com

links that has no http will not work and will become:

http://mywebsite.com/www.example.com

any ideas how to solve it?

```
function toLink($titulo){
    $url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i'; 
    $titulo = preg_replace($url, '<a href="$0" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $titulo);
    return $titulo;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert plain text URLs into HTML hyperlinks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php)

Comment: @madflow did you read my question? I think not. If you have read you would notice that I have a problem with the same function that you marked as duplicated. links with no http on it will not work.

Comment: When I try `echo toLink('google.com');` I get **google.com** is this what you want?

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz try www.google.com. it will become www.mywebsite.com/www.google.com . I'd like to add http in front of links to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback` instead and you can interrogate the match to see if you need to add the protocol.

```
function toLink($titulo) {
    $url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i'; 
    $titulo = preg_replace_callback($url, function($matches) {
        $url = $matches[0];
        if (!preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $url)) $url = 'http://'.$matches[0];
        '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank" title="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
    }, $titulo);
    return $titulo;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note also that most of your subgroups in the pattern are unnecessary since you're only using the entire match, not the sub-groups, in the output.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work but no success, should I place your code inside my toLink function?

Comment: See edit. I've now included the entire, edited function.