# How to find part of text inside array, and get his index value

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the index value of an array if there is an "http" initial value, cause the text in the string can be different in others scenario...
In this case the array will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Visit [1] => the [2] => website [3] => https://www.google.it [4] => to [5] => find [6] => other [7] => result )
```

And i need to find the [3] to build an hyperlink... this is the code that i'm try to use to get it:

```
$var = "Visit the website https://www.google.it to find other result";

if ( stripos($var, 'http') !== false ) {
    $values = explode(" ", $var);
    $key = array_search('http', $values); //<-- this not work, cause search the exact value
}
```

One time i have the index, i can build the anchor tag for hyperlink:

```
<a href="<?= $values[X] ?>">$values[X]</a>
```

I believe was easy to do, but around the web i haven't found a solution or help...
Hope in your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: You might have more luck with a [different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php).

Comment: @El_Vanja Indeed i'm here for this... do you have a solution for help me?

Comment: Try some of the methods in the linked question, see if any of them fit your needs.

Comment: Maybe `\bhttp(?:\S|[[:punct:]] |$)+`

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks a lot for your suggested link, it solve my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the PHP `filter` function as this checks if the string is a valid URL:

```php
$var = "Visit the website https://www.google.it to find other result";

$values = explode(" ", $var); // explode first

$keys_with_url = [];

foreach($values as $key => $value) { // check every element of the array if it's a valid URL
    $validator = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); 
    if($validator) {
        $keys_with_url[] = $key; // your URL index
    }
}
```

or even more compact using `array_filter` which can also find multiple occurences:

```php
$var = "Visit the website https://www.google.it or https://www.google.de to find other result";

function is_url($value) {
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
}

print_r(array_filter($values, "is_url"));
```

PHP Documentation for [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [possible filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: And why at the end you have used "break"?

Comment: This was not thought through, was assuming only one URL needs to be identified. Enhanced the example to support filtering for multiple URLs with both solution approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm going to test it on the entire my webpage...