# Encode flat text URL to clickable URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed a nice little FAQ for my site. Everything is stored in a MySQL database from Category, Question and Answer, the columns are all defined as `VARCHAR(255)`. I use the following code before adding anything I input to the database and only I have access to what gets added, edited or deleted.

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['xxxxxx'])
```

What is the best way to get the data from the database and echo it out as clickable URL's using PHP? Most of the information I have found seems to be 10 - 12 years old and many functions are now deprecated. I am not so sure security would not be an issue as it does not allow user input unless it is from myself. I know this question has been asked many times but I only find outdated code.

Comment: Is this not just a case of surrounding it with HTML `<a href` tags, or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I was not sure if that was a good idea to do it that way of if it needed some encoding or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will catch all http/https/www and convert to clickable links.

[Convert plain text URLs into HTML hyperlinks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php)

$url = '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)://[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?/';
$string= preg_replace($url, '$0', $string);
echo $string;

Comment: I will try that and post back. I did notice it came from a 12 year old post though

Comment: the best way is to rebuild URL with regex its old post but I think works well

Comment: the post above worked well, I clicked it as the answer. This is just what i was looking for. 'Tips Hat'