# php html create link from text

Tags: php, html, text

I found a routine to create a html link when a link is found in a text

```
 <?php
 function makelink($text) 
 {
 return preg_replace('/(http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*?) /i', '<a href="$1">$1</a> ', $text." "); 
 } 

 // works
 echo makelink ("hello how http://www.guruk.com ");

 // dont work
 echo makelink ("hello how http://www.guruk.com/test.php ");
```

?>

as you see in the example, it works find with a domain only, not when there is a page or subdirectory is within that link.

Can you provide a solution for that function to work also with pages and subdirs?

thx
chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add anchor tag to a URL from text input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959062/how-to-add-anchor-tag-to-a-url-from-text-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters `?=&` are for urls with query strings. Notice that I changed the separator from `/` to `!` because there a lot of slashes in your expression. Also note that you don't need `A-Z` if you are in case-insensitive mode.

```
return preg_replace('!(http://[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a> ', $text." ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should include forward slashes in its character class for the end of the url:

```
/(http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\/]*?) /i
```

That ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Without RegEx:**

```
<?php
    // take a string and turn any valid URLs into HTML links
    function makelink($input) {
        $parse = explode(' ', $input);
        foreach ($parse as $token) {
            if (parse_url($token, PHP_URL_SCHEME)) {
                echo '<a href="' . $token . '">' . $token . '</a>' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    // sample data
    $data = array(
        'test one http://www.mysite.com/',
        'http://www.mysite.com/page1.html test two http://www.mysite.com/page2.html',
        'http://www.mysite.com/?go=page test three',
        'https://www.mysite.com:8080/?go=page&test=four',
        'http://www.mysite.com/?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Ftest%2Ffive',
        'ftp://test:six@ftp.mysite.com:21/pub/',
        'gopher://mysite.com/test/seven'
    );

    // test our sample data
    foreach ($data as $text) {
        makelink($text);
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/">http://www.mysite.com/</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page1.html">http://www.mysite.com/page1.html</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page2.html">http://www.mysite.com/page2.html</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/?go=page">http://www.mysite.com/?go=page</a>
<a href="https://www.mysite.com:8080/?go=page&test=four">https://www.mysite.com:8080/?go=page&test=four</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Ftest%2Ffive">http://www.mysite.com/?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Ftest%2Ffive</a>
<a href="ftp://test:six@ftp.mysite.com:21/pub/">ftp://test:six@ftp.mysite.com:21/pub/</a>
<a href="gopher://mysite.com/test/seven">gopher://mysite.com/test/seven</a>
```