# Detect if a link is provided within text in textarea

Tags: php, textarea, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php html create link from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252727/php-html-create-link-from-text)

How can i convert written urls within text posted by user in textarea into clickable links using php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use php's preg_replace function

```
 <?
    $string = "[url]http://stackoverflow.com[/url]";
    $search = array("/\[url]([^'\"]*)\[\/url]/iU");
    $replace = array("<a href=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\">\\1</a>");
    echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

distinguish your link from the regular text by wrapping it. like [link]http://example.be[/link]

Then parse the text with php and transform the [link] tags into html link tags

or use a regular expression to detect urls in your text.

If you want more specific answers, you should make more work of your questions. Please read the [stackoverflow faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.