# Parsing text with PHP to locate url

Tags: php, regex, parsing, google-chrome, url

I have the following **php** code:

```
if(isset($_POST['text']))
      {

        $text= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

      }
```

where *$text* is utf-8. What I am trying to do is to parse the text as so to find if there are any URLs within *$text* and **tag** them accordingly. For example, if *$text* was to have:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
>   laoreet congue luctus. In fringilla mattis nisl. Vestibulum id eros
>   sed ante vestibulum faucibus. Vestibulum luctus enim sit amet ante
>   imperdiet placerat. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor
>   sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ullamcorper metus
>   vel diam consectetur, vel laoreet lectus www.google.com elementum. In ut nunc id
>   felis bibendum viverra nec quis dui. Donec non purus commodo,
>   vestibulum nisl non, lobortis eros. Ut et arcu convallis, posuere nibh
>   a, venenatis ligula. Mauris ullamcorper massa libero, placerat pretium
>   magna condimentum ut. Ut elit turpis, imperdiet pretium mauris vitae,
>   iaculis facilisis quam. Maecenas ut vulputate libero.

Then I'would like it to appear this way:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
>   laoreet congue luctus. In fringilla mattis nisl. Vestibulum id eros
>   sed ante vestibulum faucibus. Vestibulum luctus enim sit amet ante
>   imperdiet placerat. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor
>   sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ullamcorper metus
>   vel diam consectetur, vel laoreet lectus [**www.google.com**](http://www.google.com) elementum. In ut nunc id
>   felis bibendum viverra nec quis dui. Donec non purus commodo,
>   vestibulum nisl non, lobortis eros. Ut et arcu convallis, posuere nibh
>   a, venenatis ligula. Mauris ullamcorper massa libero, placerat pretium
>   magna condimentum ut. Ut elit turpis, imperdiet pretium mauris vitae,
>   iaculis facilisis quam. Maecenas ut vulputate libero.

My doubt consists in whether I should iterate through each character and try to detect an URL or run the *$text* through a regex (with php?) and attempt the same. In this last case (of the regex) how am I supposed to find the index as so to create an  tag? Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Obligatory please don't use mysql_ functions as they are depreciated.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: lol I actually wasn't aware of this. Thank you very much for this precious information!

Comment: Also check this page out it should answer your question: [Find URLs in Text, Make Links](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/)

Comment: it is indeed a duplicate @popnoodles, sorry and thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: @user3050963 ok, it's very commonplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer fairly quickly from another stackoverflow question with some quick research:

```
return preg_replace('!(http://[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a> ', $text." ");
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252897/2827066