# PHP replacing URL to a href

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP URL to Link with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393787/php-url-to-link-with-regex)

how to convert some urls in string to `<a href="here url">here url</a>`?

I'm thinking about preg_replace but what regex to use?

Thanx!

Comment: does url start with http:// or is it local urls ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not advised to use regex with html code, as HTML is a context free language, and regular expressions are most advised to use with regular languages.
Instead look into DOM libraries, as an easy way to find and replace attributes of html tags:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php