# regexp - find all matches of links

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP URL to Link with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393787/php-url-to-link-with-regex)

I am trying to **`preg_replace`** all links in a textblock, so that  they are replaced with the string `"<< IMAGE >>"`

I am trying to match all links in this text block:

```
"Here we can see the chupacabra trying to eat http://somesite.com/img/chupacabra.jpg. 
look at the the snails somesite.com/img/snails.png"
```

I am using this regexp:

**`(https?:\/\/)?.*(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)`**

But I can't get it to select only the exact strings of links.
What I need is this:

**"Here we can see the chupacabra trying to eat** `http://somesite.com/img/chupacabra.jpg`. 
**look at the the snails** `somesite.com/img/snails.png`"

Testing on [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com/)

Comment: This is not a new "problem". Please search first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems - first * ist greedy, so it matches way to much. The second is, .* includes spaces, which aren't in URLs, so you dont get the right URLs.

The simpliest solution is just to use \S which match everything except whitespaces:

```
(https?:\/\/)?\S*(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)
```

The better way is to use this one which use ?<= for lookbehind

```
(?<= |^)(https?://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(/\S*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)
```

Comment: How can I make it not match tttteerehttp://site.com/1.jpg ?

Comment: add an `\b` at the beginning to mark this as an word boundary

Comment: @Phillip testing on regexpal.com although it sounds very logical, it won't work there

Comment: ok i see.. this is because of \S which maches the invalid crap at he beginning.. try `\b(https?:\/\/)?[^ :]*(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)`

Comment: it won't match dfdfdfdfhttp://www.google.com/1.jpg just the part after http://

Comment: ok.. things become more complicated... `(?<= |^)(https?://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(/\S*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)` possible, this code doesn't work with regexpal and you have to test it in php, because of the `?<=` Syntax at the beginning

Comment: (https?://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\S*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif) This one works with regexpal -( omitted the first part), I don't know what it means, but I can't make it work on PHP. I keep getting a warning [here](http://ideone.com/58IFU2)

Comment: Sure, because you use / to seperate the regex from the modifiers. You have to use an other char like ~: `preg_replace('~(https...andsoon...)~')`

Comment: I think I found it: `preg_replace('~(https?://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\S*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)~','[[image:$0]]',$text);
` can you verify?