# Detect URL and add achor-tags around it

Tags: php, html

Recently I've developed a mailinglistsystem with PHP. Now, I'd like to make sure that if someone types a URL, the PHP-script detects it and adds the anchor-tags around it. So if I type `http://www.example.com`, this is changed into `<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>`. It doesn't matter that the displayed text is just the URL, the main issue is just adding the anchor-tags.

Is there a simple way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add anchor tag to a URL from text input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959062/how-to-add-anchor-tag-to-a-url-from-text-input)

Comment: A basic case is to use regex to find URLs but, of course, this is not a 100% method.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it's a duplicate. I had checked whether a similar question had already been posted using several titles, but I could not find it. Anyway, the accepted solution from the linked question did the job!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following regex:

```
$link = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $link);
```

It may not be perfect, but it works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

here is a little bit better version:

```
$link = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/[^\s]+\.+[a-zAZ]{2,6})/","<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $link);
```

This one checks if there is a dot in the link and a domain (like .com .org .nl)