# HTML5/PHP: How to recognize a typed in url

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I auto convert an url into a hyper link in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531502/how-do-i-auto-convert-an-url-into-a-hyper-link-in-php)

Let's say, I have an textfield on my website, where the user can enter anything he wants to.
If the user enters a url, I would like to add code to this url in the background. Therefor I would need logic in order to recognize the url.

Example
The user enters a text:

```
Please visit me at my website: http://www.mywebsite.org
```

I would like to change the code in the background to something like this:

```
Please visit me at my website: <a href="http://www.companywebsite.com/redirect.php?http://www.mywebsite.org">http://www.mywebsite.org</a>
```

How is it possible to change that link after the text has been submitted?

Comment: your html is wrong. `<a href:"..">` should be `<a href="...">`

Comment: that is a good solution on the answer you linked.  it may be noted that that answer does not consider `https` URIs though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com";

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

       // make the urls hyper links
       echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href="{$url[0]}">{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);

} else {

       // if no urls in the text just return the text
       echo $text;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving user input and displaying it on the website (as I'm guessing), you should save the raw input and apply the logic at render time.

See here for logic:
[Detect URL and add achor-tags around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647941/detect-url-and-add-achor-tags-around-it)

```
$link = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $link);
```

Comment: Slight improvement:  Replace http with http(s?) so that either http: or https: urls are matched.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also Try

```
$text = "Please visit me at my website: http://www.mywebsite.org
Please visit me at my website: http://www.mywebsite.org";
$newText    =   preg_replace('/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[^\s]+)/i',
'<a href="$1" class="link1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
echo $newText;
```

this one