# PHP regular expression find the modify the current matches

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string that I need to replace any url to be in `<a>` html tag

```
$str='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of http://www.lipsum.com/ the printing';

$outputString=
'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <a href="http://www.lipsum.com">http://www.lipsum.com/</a> the printing';
```

Comment: The `$ouputString` is invalid, you need to escape the double quotes

Comment: it's just a sample not exactly a real code, i just need tips for the answer

Comment: @AlexP not if the string is surrounded by single quotes... as it is in the OP

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before on SO. Try searching around first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959062/how-to-add-anchor-tag-to-a-url-from-text-input and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960461/convert-plain-text-urls-into-html-hyperlinks-in-php are just a few examples.

Comment: -1 and vote for close This is a duplicate and you haven't even bothered to show you have made any effort to do this yourself.

Comment: @OGHaza It was before the question was edited

Comment: @AlexP whooops, apologies, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of http://www.lipsum.com/ the printing';
$pattern='/\b((https?:\/\/|www.)[\w.\/-?=&#]+)(?=\s)/i';
$replace='<a href="$1">$1</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <a href="http://www.lipsum.com/">http://www.lipsum.com/</a> the printing'
```

[Working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37aro)

Comment: `$1` means the first capture group in the match, which in this case is the URL.

Comment: the pattern doesn't match this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4TAWrT4upY and other links

Comment: Any character you need to match just add into the `[...]` in the middle. I'll add `?`, `=`, `#` and `&` now.